# Python Image segementation and extraction

Tags: python, image-segmentation, scikit-image, feature-extraction

I am trying to figure out how to extract multiple objects from a greyscale image with mineral grains. I need to segment the different grains and then extract each of them to save as a separate image file.
While doing research, I have found that everyone uses skimage. I'm worried that some grains will not be extracted ([mineralgrains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fovAK.png)).

Has anyone had to work on a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the mineral grains are in this image, but segmenting and labeling connected components is pretty straight forward using skimage algorithms.

The simplest approach that I know of is accomplished in two major steps:

1. Generate a binary image. The most straight forward methods for this are using thresholding based methods such as those elaborated on here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_thresholding.html
2. Separating connected objects. This is often accomplished through use of a watershed algorithm as elaborated on here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_watershed.html

Assuming that the mineral grains are the bigger objects in the example image, a first pass approach may look something like the following

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage import io
from skimage.filters import gaussian, threshold_li
from skimage.morphology import remove_small_holes, remove_small_objects
from skimage.segmentation import watershed
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.measure import label

# read in the image
img = io.imread('fovAK.png', as_gray=True)

gauss_sigma = 1 # standard deviation for Gaussian kernel for removing a bit of noise from image
obj_min_size = 5000 # minimum # of pixels for labeled objects
min_hole_size = 5000 # The maximum area, in pixels, of a contiguous hole that will be filled
watershed_footprin = 100 # size of local region within which to search for peaks for watershed

#########################
#make a binary image using threshold
#########################

img_blurred = gaussian(img, gauss_sigma) # remove a bit of noise from image 
img_thresh = threshold_li(img_blurred) # use histogram based method to determine intensity threshold
img_binary = img_blurred > img_thresh # make a binary image 


# make a border around the image so that holes at edge are not filled
ydims, xdims = img.shape
img_binary[0, :] = 0
img_binary[ydims-1, :] = 0
img_binary[:, 0] = 0
img_binary[:, xdims-1] = 0

img_rsh = remove_small_holes(img_binary, min_hole_size) # removes small holdes in binary image
img_rso = remove_small_objects(img_rsh, obj_min_size) # removes small objects in binary image

#############################
#use watershed algorithm to seperate connected objects
####################################

distance = ndi.distance_transform_edt(img_rso) # distance transform of image
coords = peak_local_max(distance, labels=img_rso, footprint=np.ones((ws_footprint, ws_footprint))) # local pead distances
mask = np.zeros(distance.shape, dtype=bool) # mask for watershed
mask[tuple(coords.T)] = True
markers, _ = ndi.label(mask)
labels = watershed(-distance, markers, mask=img_rso)
```

This is absolutely a first pass on your example image and is by no means perfect. You may need to use a different thresholding algorithm or tweak other parameters but hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction.

[image]

From there you can just iterate over the labeled objects and save individual images.

There are definitely more sophisticated approaches to these kinds of problems ranging from edge detectors and bandpass filters all the out to using ML based methods but hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction.